# How to get to and from Cayo Coco in Cuba

Tags: public-transport, transportation, cuba

I am going to Cuba in a week's time and sorting out the final details of our itinerary.

My girlfriend and I will spend a couple nights in Trinidad. We would like to go spend a couple nights in Cayo Coco before going to Santiago de Cuba. The question is: how can I get to Cayo Coco from Trinidad? How can I get from Cayo Coco to Santiago de Cuba?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traveling Cuba using [Viazul](http://www.viazul.com/) buses is the best way in terms of price, comfort and safety. Unfortunately Cayo Coco is accessible by plane or taxi, and not by using Viazul buses.

You can use a taxi from Trinidad to Cayo Coco. Or you can use the Viazul from Trinidad to Ciego de Avila, and then use a taxi from Ciego de Avila to Cayo Coco.

This second option is cheaper, and on your way back you can use a taxi from Cayo Coco to Ciego de Avila, then use the Viazul bus to Santiago de Cuba or wherever else.

As soon as you arrive to the Viazul station in Ciego de Avila, you'll find lots of private taxis which can take you to Cayo Coco. Private taxis are cheaper than government taxis.

You can check Viazul prices in their website. The price of a private taxi varies, but to have an idea, a private taxi I used from [this accommodation service](http://vararent.com/services/taxi-service-to-varadero-rent-hosue-guests) from Varadero to Cayo Coco is about $240.

If you're staying in a rent house in Trinidad, your rent house owner can advice on taxi prices to Cayo Coco directly or from Ciego de Avila.

Hope it helps.